# Hibernate Date column with custom format

Tags: java, hibernate, date

I have to map a column in a hibernate pojo. The issue I'm running into is that the column I want to use is a `VARCHAR2(6 CHAR)`, but it is a string of a date in the format of `mmYYYY`. I'd like to actually map it to be a date.

I've been looking through various resources, and I've tried a number of things.

```
@Column(name = "EXP_DATE")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "mmYYYY")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date expiration;
```

However, it doesn't seem like the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation doesn't actually seem to be relevant to what I want to do. It isn't reading the format I supply and throws an exception when it tries to parse the string into a date

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
```

UPDATE:
I do have to note, I cannot actually modify any of the XML configs so it has to be done with annotations. It's less than ideal, but it is the current situation I have.

UPDATE:
Delving a little deeper into the @DateTimeFormat annotation, I had the wrong capitalization. I should have been using "MMyyyy", to further continue it does not seem like the formatter will accept any format that does not include the day. For now, I am going to map this to a String unless someone replies back with a working solution.

Thanks all involved.

Comment: missing day of the year in this pattern, you are using Spring too?

Comment: The day is intentionally missing. if possible, I'd like to make that the first day of that month implicitly. As far as spring goes, I do have access to spring annotations (it may require some wiring on my part due to the fact we're in mid-migration from our in-house solution to spring).

Comment: okay, what format you want to save the date in the database?

Comment: The column is a string of 6 characters in the format of "mmYYYY" (See the first paragraph of the question).

Comment: If you want to save as string limits the field to 6 characters and works with management dates and strings from java, do not complicate with hibernate
TemporalType has another purpose

Comment: There are valid reasons to do what I am attempting to do, namely reinventing the wheel for Date manipulations. Should I need to arbitrarily add 32 months to this date, I now need to write methods and tests for those methods to ensure that the math is done correctly. In this instance it may be trivial, but with many people using the library we are writing, the margin of error rises significantly and errors are more prone to occur. It is better to use the core Date libraries than to implement an situation specific String manipulation class to manipulate a single field, which in concept is a date

Comment: Have you tried [`pattern()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#pattern--) method?

Comment: I would love to, but unfortunately I work elsewhere now. I no longer have access to the project to try. Thanks though!

Comment: If someone comes up with a working answer that others can verify works by up-voting, I will select it to resolve the question